# Como procurar um elemento com o querySelector filtrando pelo innerText?

Tags: javascript, query

Gostaria de saber como posso através do `querySelector` (ou de qualquer outra função) obter um ou mais elementos (`<div>`, `<a>`, `<button>`, ...), filtrando através do conteúdo do `innerText`.

No documento abaixo por exemplo, eu quero obter qualquer tipo de elemento que possua no `innerText` a string `"bola"`. Como eu poderia fazer isso usando JavaScript?

```js
/*
A função abaixo é um exemplo que deve retornar os seguintes elementos:
<h1> - Linha 1
<a> - Linha 3
<div> - Linha 7
<div> - Linha 10
<span> - Linha 14
*/

const results = getElementsByInnerText("bola");
```

```html
<h1>bola</h1>
<div id="something0">
    <a href="some link" class="something2">bola</a>
    <a href="some link2" class="something2">carro</a>
    <div class="some class">
        <div class="some class2">
            <div id="some id">bola</div>
            <div>casa</div>
        </div>
        <div>bola</div>
        <div class="something2">avião</div>
    </div>
</div>
<span>bola</span>
```

Comment: Isso aqui te ajuda? [Get Elements By InnerText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3813294/how-to-get-element-by-innertext)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É possível selecionar todos os elementos e depois filtrar eles pelo valor do atributo `innerText`. Confira-se a seguinte função:

```
const queryByInnerText = (text) => {
    return [...document.body.querySelectorAll('*')].filter(e => e.innerText === text);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Como @JassRiver disse, mas fiz um exemplo para você.

Positive o comentário dele caso ajudou!

```js
const 

aTag = document.getElementById("id-elemento"),

searchText = "bola",

found = [];

for (let i = 0; i < aTag.length; i++) {

  if (aTag[i].textContent == searchText)
  
    found.push(aTag[i]);
  
}

console.log (found)
```

```html
<select id="id-elemento" name="existingList">
  <option value="1">bola</option>
  <option value="2">pedra</option>
  <option value="3">bola</option>
</select>
```

Obs: se quiser que explique cada linha me fala no comentário que edito.

Answer (score 0):

Isso provavelmente não é uma boa ideia...

Se, no futuro, for determinado que é melhor pro negócio usar a palavra "esfera" no lugar de "bola", e, portanto, deve ser trocado os termos nas aplicações, o próximo desenvolvedor, ou você mesmo, achará estranho que uma troca simples de um texto faça que determinada funcionaldidade deixe de funcionar. Alterações em outros pontos que adicione "bola" ao conteúdo ou textos dinâmicos poderiam causar bugs e precisariam ser tratados adequadamente (o que, geralmente, não vale a pena)

Além disso, não existe uma API nativa para fazer o que deseja, e qualquer solução criada involve a busca em todos os elementos do DOM e depois filtrar, o que pode ser custoso, dependendo da situação

A solução ideal seria alterar o elemento, adicionando uma classe ou atributo pra ser utilizado como filtro:

```
<!-- document.querySelector('.bola') -->
<h1 class="bola">bola</h1>

<!-- ou -->

<!-- document.querySelector('[tipo="bola"]') -->
<h1 tipo="bola">bola</h1>
```

Mas, se for analisado, e a melhor solução for realmente fazer uma busca pelo conteúdo do elemento, segue uma solução que tende a ser um pouco melhor que buscar em tudo:

```js
((window) => {
  window.Element.prototype.getElementsByContent = function(search) {
    console.log('searching in', this);
    if (this.children.length === 0)
      return this.innerText === search ? [this] : [];

    let elements = [];

    for (const child of this.children)
      if (child.innerHTML.indexOf(search) !== -1)
        elements = elements.concat(child.getElementsByContent(search))
      else
        console.log('skip searching in', child);

    return elements;
  };
})(this);

console.log(document.body.getElementsByContent('bola'));
```

```html
<h1>bola</h1>
<div id="something0">
    <a href="some link" class="something2">bola</a>
    <a href="some link2" class="something2">carro</a>
    <div class="some class">
        <div class="some class2">
            <div id="some id">barco</div>
            <div>casa</div>
        </div>
        <div>bola</div>
        <div class="something2">avião</div>
    </div>
</div>
<span>bola</span>
```

Nessa solução, não é simplesmente procurado em tudo, é feito uma verificação simples se o elemento DOM tem, em qualquer lugar, o texto procurado, o que permite pular certos blocos, como em `<div class="some class">`, já que não possui, pula todos os elementos abaixo dele. Nesse exemplo, não faz muita diferença, pois é pequeno e poucos elementos são pulados, porém, em situações reais pode deixar de fazer a busca desnecessária em dezenas de elementos

Outra observação importante, a busca é feita através do elemento base, no exemplo, `document.body`, se você tem controle de onde os elementos estão, pode usar um elemento mais a baixo e restringir melhor a busca, se a fizer a partir de `document.getElementById('something0')`, não será verificado o primeiro e último elemento (`h1` e `span`)

Mas essa é uma solução simples, se o texto de busca for na verdade uma classe ou id ou parte dele, por exemplo, `<div class="bolacha"></div>` a verificação se contém a string "bola" retornará verdadeiro, porém o "bola" encontrado é de "bolacha" além de ser uma classe e não o contúdo do elemento